# Filling missing values pandas dataframe

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to fill missing datavalues in a pandas dataframe based on date column.

```
df.head()

            col1 col2 col3
date            
2014-06-20  3    752     4028
2014-06-21  4    752     4028
2014-06-22  32   752     4028
2014-06-25  44   882     4548
2014-06-26  32   882     4548
```

I tried the following

```
idx = pd.date_range(df.index[0], df.index[-1])

df = df.reindex(idx).reset_index()
```

But, I get a dataframe of nans.

```
    index       col1 col2   col3
0   2014-06-20  NaN  NaN    NaN
1   2014-06-21  NaN  NaN    NaN
2   2014-06-22  NaN  NaN    NaN
3   2014-06-23  NaN  NaN    NaN
4   2014-06-24  NaN  NaN    NaN
```

What am I missing here ?

Comment: Do you definitely have a `DatetimeIndex` in your original DataFrame or are the dates just strings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior you describe would happen if the index is a `pd.Index` containing
*strings*, rather than a `pd.DatetimeIndex` containing timestamps.

For example,

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'col1': [3, 4, 32, 44, 32],
     'col2': [752, 752, 752, 882, 882],
     'col3': [4028, 4028, 4028, 4548, 4548]},
    index = ['2014-06-20', '2014-06-21', '2014-06-22', '2014-06-25', '2014-06-26'])

idx = pd.date_range(df.index[0], df.index[-1])
print(df.reindex(idx).reset_index())
#        index  col1  col2  col3
# 0 2014-06-20   NaN   NaN   NaN
# 1 2014-06-21   NaN   NaN   NaN
# 2 2014-06-22   NaN   NaN   NaN
# 3 2014-06-23   NaN   NaN   NaN
# 4 2014-06-24   NaN   NaN   NaN
# 5 2014-06-25   NaN   NaN   NaN
# 6 2014-06-26   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

whereas, in contrast, if you make the index a DatetimeIndex:

```
df.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.index)
```

then

```
print(df.reindex(idx).reset_index())
       index  col1  col2  col3
0 2014-06-20     3   752  4028
1 2014-06-21     4   752  4028
2 2014-06-22    32   752  4028
3 2014-06-23   NaN   NaN   NaN
4 2014-06-24   NaN   NaN   NaN
5 2014-06-25    44   882  4548
6 2014-06-26    32   882  4548
```

Comment: Ah. I missed this subtle part ! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Pandas has a builtin method to achieve this. Have a look at http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html .

You can use `df.asfreq('1d')` to resample your data based on the date column and fill in the missing values automatically.